# Can I inject IKernel into class with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to inject AuthenticationService without using new:

```
IAuthenticationService authenticationService = null;
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"] == null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"] = new AuthenticationService();
}
authenticationService = (AuthenticationService)HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"];
```

I was thinking of using kernel.Get  (), but I do not know if it's a good practice to inject IKernel. I was also thinking of using a factory, but I do not know how to combine it with Ninject.

What would you advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not inject IKernel into a class and it should not be necessary to do so if you are properly leveraging the IOC container provided by Ninject. You can set up your binding for the service similar to the following:

`kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AuthenticationService>();`

note that depending on how you have Ninject setup, this could occur in a few different places. If you supply more code, I can elaborate on where this goes. For many, it is in the NinjectWebCommon.cs class.

then in whatever class you want to inject `IAuthenticationService` into, simply pass in the `IAuthenticationService` like the following:

```
public class WhateverClass
{
  private IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

  public WhateverClass(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
  {
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }

  //some other properties or methods that make use of authentication service here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I plan to inject WhateverClass InSingletonScope and I would like to have a new instance of AuthenticationService every time.

Comment: This should still work for you- Your binding for `WhateverClass` will look like `kernel.Bind<IWhateverClass>().To<WhateverClass>().InSingletonScope();` or if you dont have an interface for it: `kernel.Bind<WhateverClass>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope()`